# Oracle SQL: Trying to exclude rows based on a combination of column values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle11gr2

I have a table with a list of IDs that I need to exclude rows from. For each row, an ID can have one value in the comment_code column. I need to exclude IDs from my results that have a combination of two specific values and keep IDs that have only one of those two values. Sorry if this isn't clear.

Table example:

```
ID     SEQUENCE     FUNCTION     COMMENT_CODE
---------------------------------------------------------------
1        1             tree          apple
1        2             bush          orange
2        1             tree          apple
2        2             tree          banana
3        1             bush          strawberry
```

Output needed:

```
ID     SEQUENCE     FUNCTION     COMMENT_CODE
---------------------------------------------------------------
2        1             tree          apple
```

Basically, if an ID has a row with 'apple' as the comment_code and a row with 'orange' as the comment code, I don't want to see that ID in my results. If an ID has a row with 'apple' as a comment code, I want to see them in my results regardless of any other comment_code they may have as long as they don't have the orange comment code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried using a combination of exists and not exists clauses as well as listagg to group the comment_code values together for each ID, but I'm not getting the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach uses aggregation to find all `id`s that have both values.  This is used as an exclusion list using a `left outer join`:

```
select *
from table t left outer join
     (select id
      from table t
      group by t.id
      having sum(case when comment = 'apple' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
             sum(case when comment = 'orange' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
     ) toexclude
     on t.id = toexclude.id
where toexclude.id is null;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! I added " AND T.COMMENT = 'apple' " and I'm now getting the expected results. I thought about doing a CASE yesterday, but I just couldn't visualize how to get it to work in this situation.

Comment: when you said `group by t` did you mean `group by id` ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
select *
from yourtable
where sequence = 1
and whatever
```

Comment: Dan, I should add that there are several different comment codes on the real table in no particular order for each ID, so the sequence value isn't really relevant. The 'apple' comment code could be on sequence 1 or it could be on sequence 99, it just depends the order in which the comment codes were added to the ID.

Comment: Then how do you know which comments you want?

Comment: For the example, the comment I want is 'apple'. I was able to get what I needed using Gordon's example and adding an additional criteria.

Answer (score -1):

select *
  from table t
 where exists (select 1 from dual
                where t.function = 'tree'
                  and t.comment_code = 'apple')

Comment: When answering, explain what you have to to solve the original problem. Also use proper formatting for codes.